# How to customize injected instance based on injection context?

Tags: c#, autofac

I'm currently working on migrating an application from `Ninject` to `Autofac 4`. We had a logic to set some properties of a resolved class instance before it gets injected into *somewhere^. In `Ninject` we did it like this.

```
// Ninject setup example
this.Bind<IServiceContext>()
    .To<DefaultServiceContext>()
    .InCallScope()
    .OnActivation((ctx, instance) =>
    {
        if (instance.Module == null) {
            instance.Module = ctx.Request.Target.Member.DeclaringType.FullName;
        }
    });
```

The key in the code is that using `ctx.Request.Target.Member` we could access the constructor info (in case of constructor injection of course) where the ongoing injection happens. So we could initialize our injected service class by setting its `Module` property to the injection target type name.

I cannot find anything similar in `Autofac`. I've tried both the `OnActivating` and `OnActivated` hooks, but those seem not to provide this information and seem to mean slightly different thing compared to `Ninject`'s hooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instance can be shared across lifetimescope. To avoid any side effect *Autofac* doesn't let us know which component requested the activated component.

By the way you can create a custom parameter that will take care of injecting all your `IServiceContext`. By using a module you can add this custom parameter to every component. This way you will know which type requested your `IServiceContext`

This module will give you access to the target type when a `T` is requested.

```
public class TargetPreparingCallbackModule<T> : Module
{

    public TargetPreparingCallbackModule(Func<Type, Parameter> targetPreparing)
    {
        this._targetPreparing = targetPreparing;
    }

    private readonly Func<Type, Parameter> _targetPreparing;

    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry,
            IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        registration.Preparing += this.Registration_Preparing;
    }

    private void Registration_Preparing(object sender, PreparingEventArgs e)
    {
        var t = e.Component.Activator.LimitType;

        e.Parameters = e.Parameters.Union(
            new[]
            {
                new ResolvedParameter(
                    (p, c) => p.ParameterType == typeof (T),
                    (p, c) => {
                        Parameter parameter =  this._targetPreparing(t);
                        T instance = c.Resolve<T>(parameter);
                        return instance;
                    })
            });
    }
}
```

you can then use it like this :

```
builder.RegisterModule(
    new TargetPreparingCallbackModule<Foo>(targetType => new NamedParameter("module", targetType.FullName)));
```

You can also use the `Activating` or `Activated` event of the target if you want to have access to the target instance.

Comment: Thank you, I thought there must be some design decisions behind this. I'll give this approach a try.